# How to click on 2FA 'Duo Push Button' using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a 2FA 'Send me a push' button, however none of my previous attempts have succeeded

```
def launch_login():
    #open login web page

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get("http://my.csus.edu")
    #enter login

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']").send_keys("xxxxxxxx")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']").send_keys("xxxxxxxx")
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")
    login.click()
    #click duo push button

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(@class, 'positive auth-button') and contains(., 'Send Me a Push')]").click()

    return driver
driver = launch_csus()
```

This is error I am receiving

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[starts-with(@class, 'positive auth-button') and contains(., 'Send Me a Push')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.41)
```

I am still pretty new to selenium and am learning as I go. Is the button a special type of button that behaves in a certain way? Is there a specific way to access the button?

Send me a push inspect:

[image: Send me a push inspect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button with the text as ***Send Me a Push*** is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

[image: duo_iframe]

---

### Solution

So to click on <kbd>Send Me a Push</kbd> you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  driver.get("http://my.csus.edu")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']"))).send_keys("xxxxxxx")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']").send_keys("xxxxxxxx")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Login')]").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='duo_iframe']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Send Me a Push']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: idp]